Screens black when waking up if external monitor is hooked up
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo Legion 5. I use a monitor hooked up to my laptop via USB-C, but notice that after a suspend, on waking, the screens remain black. I can enter inputs (put in my password and hit enter to log in), but nothing visually. I have to unplug the monitor for anything to appear. This doesn't happen when waking up from a suspend with the monitor not plugged in.
